# Icon size in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, image, navigationbar

I have a navigation drawer in my app. I am making an HTTP request to load in friends and group names along with the pics. I want my pics to resize so they can adjust in. This is what i have

[image]

This is what i want

[image]

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            int k=0;
            for(String n : friends){
                String words[] = n.split(":");
                menu.findItem(R.id.friends).getSubMenu().add(R.id.friends, Integer.parseInt(words[1]),k,words[0]);
                MenuItem myMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.friends).getSubMenu().findItem(Integer.parseInt(words[1]));
                DownloadImageTask dn = new DownloadImageTask(myMenuItem);
                dn.execute(AppConfig.IMAGESURL + words[2]);
      }
}
    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<MenuItem> menuItemReference;

        public DownloadImageTask(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItemReference = new WeakReference<>(menuItem);
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (menuItemReference != null) {
                MenuItem menuitem = menuItemReference.get();
                if (menuitem != null) {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        Drawable r = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
                        menuitem.setIcon(r);
                    } else {
                        //  Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
                        // imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: good ask zuckerberg! anyway save loaded data (friend/group) to array and then drawer items

Comment: I can't find resizing the pic part in your answer

Comment: Just provide the code that is related to placing the icons. We don't really need the entire application. Check out this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583757/resizing-a-bitmap).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I have minimize my code please have a look

Comment: you can import svg and use it instead.

Comment: I can't i have to fetch data from my web