# What does virtual display in Android do with Image pixels when smaller display dimensions are set than grabbed one?

Tags: java, android, screen, pixel, image-resizing

I dont understand what happens with pixels in Virtual Display in Android when output dimensions are reduced compared to the input ones ?

When I have for example input = size of my Display = 1920x960 and I set outputs to be 1920/3 and 960/3, what happens in that case with image pixels:

1. pixel density is increased or
2. maybe it takes only smaller part of screen that is centered and has dimensions 640x320 or
3. something else?

Additionally, is there a way that I can only grab center part of screen as in picture below?

[image: Desired region]

Comment: Hmm, the question itself doesn't seem to be a [question fit for the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since it talks about how the OS handles rendering and doesn't concern any problem or a topic about programming at all. BUT your last question about screen grabbing or screen capturing does sound like a plausible question. Maybe move this thread to another Meta site ([SuperUser perhaps](https://superuser.com/))and ask your last question on a separate thread.

Comment: First question is there because I am not 100% sure how that works and maybe my second question can be solved that way. I saw tons of similar questions here so dont see anything wrong with it...

Comment: My point here is that this is supposed to be asked on a site like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) since this talks about how would the software/hardware adapt to decreasing pixel size(s) of a rendered object. It really isn't on-topic for StackOverflow because this is the place where you ask questions about programming and not hardware/software specific questions.

Comment: Also, you can get a better guarantee that someone will actually answer your questions if you ask this on a site like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Note: this question has already been [reasked on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1731278/356789), but was then [migrated to Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247503/44325).

Comment: Eek, can't believe this has been migrated to 2 other sites already and went unanswered.

Comment: Oh I see, you asked it with the last question in mind, I thought you were only going to ask about "[Android] how would the OS handle resizing to smaller display dimensions?" and not about " Is there a way that I can only grab center part of screen as in picture below?". My bad.

Comment: I'll watch some and dig in the AOSP, come back once I have a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

By digging in the [AOSP](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java;l=1?q=Bitmap.java&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject), [watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdQRIYOST64), looking at a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583757/resizing-a-bitmap) and experimenting~

I have come to my own (might be overly) simplified conclusion.

1. Android calls the native Java SDK which produces the information that's needed to render a bitmap/pixels on a Java program.
2. If the results are the same don't need to pass/copy it again to the GPU.
3. If the results are not the same pass/copy it to the GPU to be "invalidated" then re-rendered.

Now to your question.

1. By looking at the [Bitmap](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java;l=1?q=Bitmap.java&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) class and looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583757/resizing-a-bitmap) It came to my mind that resizing depends on the scaling ratio passed on to the [Matrix](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Matrix.java;l=1?q=Matrix.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) class.
2. If resized, it will expensively create a new Bitmap that looks like something either a pretty-bad higher pixel-density or not-so-smooth lower pixel density.
3. If the pixel-density is increased (smaller dimensions, your case) it will look squashed and if need be, the colors are averaged to the nearest neighbouring pixels. ("kind of" like how [JPEG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kv1Hiv3ox8I) works).
4. After resizing it will still stay to it's origin (top-left part of the rendered object) which is defined by it's X and Y coordinates.

For your second question, about screen grabbing you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) and then programatically resize the image by doing something like this:

```java
  //...
  Bitmap.createBitmap(screenshot_bitmap, left, top, right, bottom);
  //...
```